# QAF-Feature file facing issue to access multilingual chars

Tags: qaf

Problem:
I am facing issue in pass multilingual characters to global QAF methods.
Steps:

- And I assert link with text "ਪੰਜਾਬੀ" is present
- And I assert link with text "தமிழ்" is present

```
@QAFTestStep(description = "I assert link with text {linkText} is present")
    public static void iAssertLinkWithTextPresent(String linkText) {
        System.out.println("The text is:" + linkText);
        assertLinkWithTextPresent(linkText);
    }
```

Output:
The text is: à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à¯?

Kindly provide any solution to access the multilingual characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried and it works fine for me. One of the possible reason is text encoding of editor not compatible, resulting alteration to the file. You can try setting encoding of editor you (and all other team members) are using.

I am using eclipse and for Eclipse i have default encoding `UTF-8`. If you are using eclipse, you can go to Preferences>General>Workspace and select `UTF-8` as the Text File Encoding.

[image: Eclipse Text File Encoding]

Comment: Its working as expected. Yes. along with I have added below line in my pom.xml
```<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.9</version>
 <configuration>
  **<argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>**
        </configuration>